# Why can't Google Play Services find right version after Update - Expected 5077000 but found 1013

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, ads

After reinstalling Eclipse and Android SDK due to an update bug by Google, I was able to get SDK version 23.2x and my google play services (g.p.s.) was revision 18 . I do not have adMob SDK, only g.p.s.. After doing this, **my ads stopped showing up**. I was able to trace the problem to the message that: **Google Play services out of date. Requires 5077000 but found 1013**. There is also a message that says Google Play Services failed to load because of error 2 (which I assume is because of the incorrect version).

I opened up my values.xml in Google play services and it says that the version is 5077000. I am certain that I have everything installed correctly, since **my app was working perfectly before I updated**.

My code was extensively tested and fully functional I do not think posting would help since it is not code related to my knowledge.

I was wondering why Google Play Services cannot find the right version and where is this 1013 coming from. I just want to know why my ads will not come up and how to fix these messages. I know that a few people are having this issue, maybe somebody came up with a solution? Google is really treating some of us poorly with these faulty updates, I have been stuck for a week trying to fix these issues. I am **running on version 17 (Android 4.2.2) for physical device and emulator** btw.

Please be considerate.  I am new to this site. Thank you!

Comment: From what I have found, Google has had these issues before.  However, they simply took down the newest version temporarily until they had it fixed.  They are not doing this now and they haven't responded to forum posts, so maybe only a few people are experiencing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out that the device I was testing on did not have updated Google Play Services.  After updating, my ads started to show up again.  In order to update, I just checked for isGooglePlayServicesAvailable with a non-intrusive error notification.  I will post code later today

**EDIT:** Added code

```
    if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)==ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED);{
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this),
            this);
    }
```